# CSS text-decoration:none; doesn't work

Tags: html, css

So i was reading a tutorial online about flexbox and tried to make a dropdown menu. But the only thing which doesn't work is that the text-decoration:none has no effect at all? i have to use color#fff to make the text white?

also why do i need to use the + sign and i cant use the > sign when displaying the dropdown menu?

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  z-index;
  1000;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(54, 194, 182, 0.96) 0, rgba(62, 188, 207, 0.96) 100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
header nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin 0;
  padding 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}
header nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
header nav ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(58, 162, 173, 1);
}
header nav ul li a {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.55rem;
  font-weight: 200px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  max-width: 130px;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header nav ul li a + ul {
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 195px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(58, 162, 173, 1) 0, rgba(62, 188, 207, 0.96) 100%);
  ;
}
header nav ul li:hover a + ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
              Home
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/blog">
              Blog
            </a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Me</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Gaming</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sport</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Development</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/contact">      
                Contact      
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/forum">
                Forum
            </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: `text-decoration: none` works when I put your code in a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjQEAX

Comment: `text-decoration` does not change color, it removes the anchors underline

Comment: _"also why do i need to use the + sign and i cant use the > sign when displaying the dropdown menu?"_ - I can only guess that you neglected to properly escape it for the context you put it in. (If you don't have the styles in a separate file, but in the HTML somewhere, then `>` has to be `&gt;` of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-decoration` does not change color, it removes the anchors underline

The immediate sibling selector `+` is needed because targeted element is not a child of the `a` element, its a sibling

So when you use a rule like this, you'll need the `+`

```
header nav ul li:hover a + ul {
  display: block;
}
```

But if you change it like this you can use `>`

```
header nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Heh just updated my answer and saw we had said basically the exact same thing xD Nice :D

Comment: @JacobGray Yepp, see that now ... and I posted mine just because your initial answer didn't address the selector issue in the question ... which means we just have to be right, right ? .. :)

Answer (score 1):

[`text-decoration:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) removes the default underline of links, it doesn't change the color.

Like you said, if you want white text, set the `<a>`'s color to `white`(or the equivalent):

```
header nav ul li a {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.55rem;
  font-weight: 200px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  max-width: 130px;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbywbqyx/)

*also why do i need to use the + sign and i cant use the > sign when displaying the dropdown menu?*

I assume you are referencing the selectors that look like `header nav ul li a + ul` in your CSS. This is because the `+` and `>` combinators have different meanings. `+` is the adjacent sibling combinator, so in this case:

```
<a href="/blog">Blog</a> Hover over the a
<ul></ul> Select the ul that is an adjacent sibling
```

This combinator isn't even needed, you can simply do:

```
header nav ul li > ul
```

Which selects the `<ul>` that is a child of the `<li>`

Comment: So 1 up from me :)